Passing out dynamic value in a azure monitor
We are using a webhook to pass dynamic values from KQL driven alerts in Azure monitor into Jira
The only way Ive worked out to create the dynamic values is by using them as dimensions in the summarise step
Event
 | where EventID == 999 and Source == 'AILog' and TimeGenerated > ago(1455m)
 | extend ExtProps = parse_json(RenderedDescription) 
 | project TimeGenerated 
      ,process = ExtProps["Process"] 
      ,File_name = ExtProps["FileName"]
      ,Filesize = ExtProps["Size"]
      ,Client = ExtProps["Client"]
 | where process =='Send trans to Clover SFTP'
 | summarize Trigger = count()
        ,Client = max(tostring(Client))
        ,MasterProject ='XXX'
        ,Priority ='XXX'
        ,AlertName ="XXX"
        ,Context = "XXx"

The only real dynamic value is the client because this is a generic alert and the client changes.
This then allows me to set up each dimension in the split by dimension step in azure alerting.
This is super clunky and prone to error.
So anyone got idea how I can improve this?

What kind of output you want to have? And what do you exactly mean with "dynamic values"?

So we have API calls for customer X and Y - only customer Y API calls are failing, I want customer Y to be sent out as a value. THe only way I found to do this is to summarise by customer

How do you recognize Client Y? You could just add a WHERE clause and filter out everything else. And maybe extend your projections and execute tostring() on them, to get rid of these dynamic values.

In the Powershell that writes all the JSOn to the event log, we pass in the client. Yes I could add a where but that would mean I'd need alert X for client X and Alert X for client Y and that is what I am trying to avoid
